# Is 0.1 - 0.3 seconds is good pageload time?

Tags: forum, page-load-time, mybb

My forum (runnin mybb) generates pages mostly in 0.1 - 0.24 seconds (mostly 87% PHP / 13% MySQL)

Is this okay? what can i do to reduce this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a reverse proxy, optimise your database, caching engine, use a faster stack (aka. anything-but-Apache or PHP opcode caching or buy a better server.

If you have time, do a bit of reading on Varnish, APC, optimising  and nginx.

Although 0.3s isn't slow, its not a magic number either. Off-the-shelf forum software tends to be a little bit large and bulky, and I honestly don't think most people will ever use all the functions in it. You'd be aiming for something like 0.1s page generation for a true "fast site".